# List of Call for papers

Tags: journals

Is there somewhere a list of ongoing *Call for papers* for special issues in OR journals?

I believe that such a list would not only create a good overview for publication opportunities but also inform about current research trends in the field.

Comment: http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/